# Relationship between rank and independent columns

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the proof that the rank is the number of independent columns trivial? E.g. if matrix $A:m\times n$ has rank $k$, you can say directly that it has $k$ linearly independent columns?

Comment: How did you define rank. Often, it is defined as the number of linearly independent columns.

Answer (score 0):

The proof that the column rank and the row rank *coincide* for all matrices is probably what you're looking for.

It's not trivial: one way to prove it is through the fact that the rank of $M$ is the minimal number $k$, such that $M$ is the sum of $k$ matrices of rank $1$.